# How can I copy files from subfolders? (list of filenames is in a text file) using the command line and perl

Tags: perl, batch-file, copy, cmd, subdirectory

I want to search for list of files in a folder and its subfolders, and copy results to a different folder.

I'm currently using:

```
for /F "delims==" %i in (listimagescopy.txt) do copy "V:\Photo Library\%i.jpg" "V:\Current Library\Work Zone"
```

there are sub folders in 'photo library' & i need that the command line should look in the sub folders too for the files listed in 'listimagescopy.txt'

*also* within the sub folders there may be 2 files with the same name - i would need to be able to specify that when looking in folders for files from the list it should return the newer version of each file (or if this is to complicated to do with the cmd it would also be okay if when it copies the files they are named differently ex file1 file2)

Comment: What is your question?  The snippet you listed will already copy the files listed in the .txt file.  Are you wanting a script that will take a search token and copy the files that match the token?

Comment: until now 'photo library' was just one folder & now I have added sub folders within 'photo library' and I need to be able to do the same command only it should also look for the files in subfolders

Comment: Should be asked at serverfault.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Batch solution:**

You could use [FOR /R](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) to list all the subfolders:

```
FOR /R "V:\Photo Library" %G in (.) do @echo %G
```

and launch your command, slightly modified, for every folder:

```
FOR /R "V:\Photo Library" %G in (.) do for /F "delims=" %i in (listimagescopy.txt) do xcopy "%G\%i.jpg" "V:\Current Library\Work Zone" /D /Y
```

xcopy /D will copy only newer files, /Y overwrites without confirm. In a batch file, checking if source exists, you could use this:

```
@echo off
FOR /R "V:\Photo Library" %%G in (.) do (
  for /F "delims=" %%i in (listimagescopy.txt) do (
    if exist "%%G\%%i.jpg" xcopy "%%G\%%i.jpg" "V:\Current Library\Work Zone" /D /Y
  )
)
```

**Perl solution:**

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use File::Copy;

#filenames to match
my $filenames = join '|', map "\Q$_\E", split "\n", <<END;
filename1
otherfilename
another_one
etc
END

my $src_path = "V:\\Photo Library";
my $dst_path = "V:\\Current Library\\Work Zone";

find({ wanted => \&process_file, no_chdir => 1 }, $src_path);

sub process_file {
  if (-f $_) {
    # it's a file
    if (/\/($filenames).jpg$/) {
      # it matches one of the rows
      if ((stat($_))[9] > ((stat("$dst_path/$1.jpg"))[9] // 0)) {
        # it's newer than the file in the destination
        # or destination file does't exist
        print "copying $_ ...\n";
        copy($_, $dst_path) or die "File $_ cannot be copied.";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: am i supposed to just paste it in?

Comment: when i just paste it in- i get this--  @echo off
FOR /R "V:\Photo Library" %%G in (.) do (
_%%G was unexpected at this time._
  for /F "delims=" %%i in (listimagescopy.txt) do (
_%%i was unexpected at this time._
    if exist "%%G\%%i.jpg" xcopy "%%G\%%i.jpg" "V:\Current Library\Work Zone" /D /Y
  )
)

Comment: @june paste the last piece of code in a .CMD file, and launch it. Or you could just paste the second line starting with FOR. It tries to copy every file, even ones that don't exist, but it will just skip them

Comment: just for interest sake- i just looked at your profile & i see you mentioned perl im interested in perl too though i dont really know it well   -if its not too complicated i wouldnt mind knowing how to do the same thing but in perl i believe it would be more flexible (and i can get live assistance if i want to tweak the script)

Comment: @fthiella Errm, about that Perl snippet: using `stat` in scalar context isn't going to do anything useful. You probably want to find out when the file was last altered: `if(-M $_ < -M "$dst_path/$1.jpg" or not -e _) {...}`. `-M` returns how old the last modification to a file is, in days, so you will want to copy from `$_` if it is younger, or the target doesn't exist.

Comment: Consider `my $filenames = join '|', map "\Q$_\E", split "\n", <<END;` and then remove the two substitutions, in case there are meta-characters in the file names which may impact the regex matching.

Comment: @amon yes, stat is not correct, thanks, updated to use `stat()[9]`, and i am also setting its value to 0 with `// 0` when second file doesn't exist to avoid warning

Comment: @fthiella thanks for your assistance everthing is working out great